# How to Generate Fuchu Unit testCases in for loop

Tags: f#

I'm trying to generate random unit tests in F# with Fuchu.

I'm executing my code in Vs 2017 with a normal Console App.

The issue is that `GeneraterandomTests` will not compile.

```
open Fuchu

let OpenOrSenior xs = 
    [for (x:List<int>) in xs do
        if x.[0] >= 55 && x.[1] > 7 then yield "Senior" else yield "Open"]

let rand = new Random()

type ClubMember = {Age:int;Handi:int}

let values =  [
        {Age = 10;Handi=2}
        {Age=25;Handi=9}
        {Age=75;Handi=2}
        {Age=20;Handi=25}
        {Age=1;Handi=1}
        {Age=90;Handi=8}
        {Age=79;Handi=12}
        {Age=99;Handi=18}
        {Age=75;Handi=8}
        {Age=76;Handi=9}
    ]


let SelectMember (mem:ClubMember) = 
    match mem with 
    | x when (mem.Age >= 55) && (mem.Handi > 7) -> "Senior"
    | _ -> "Open"


let PutAttributesInList (mem:ClubMember) = 
    match mem with 
    | _ -> [mem.Age; mem.Handi]

let Randomtests expected actual = testCase "Randomness"  <|
                                        fun _ ->  Assert.Equal("expected == actual?", OpenOrSenior expected, actual)

[<Tests>]
let GeneraterandomTests = 

    for i in 1..10 do 
        let mutable expected:int list list = []
        let mutable actual: string list = []
        for _i in 1..5 do 
            let mutable rndNumb = rand.Next(0,9)
            actual <- SelectMember values.[rndNumb] :: actual
            expected <- PutAttributesInList values.[rndNumb] :: expected
        Randomtests expected actual
```

Comment: "will not compile" is not a good description of a problem.

Comment: I think you need to unindent the last line by two levels. You obviously intended it to be the return value of the function, but right now it's within the inner for loop.

Comment: Still does not work I want to test it 10 times and it still does not work

Comment: If you want to get help, you'll have to describe the problem better than "does not work".

Comment: The test will not compile

Comment: What's the compile error saying?

Comment: Fyodor Soikin has given you the right answer in his second comment, but when you edited the code you only unindented it by *one* level. You should have unintended the last line by one more level, so that it lines up with the `for i in 1..10` line.

Comment: That does not work I actually want testCasesList to have 10 different Unit tests then test testCaseList in __suit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in Visual studio 2017 and compiles and tests, it's with Fuchu

```
// random test cases...
open Fuchu
open System
let rand = new Random()

type ClubMember = {Age:int;Handi:int}

let values =  [
        {Age = 10;Handi=2}
        {Age=25;Handi=9}
        {Age=75;Handi=2}
        {Age=20;Handi=25}
        {Age=1;Handi=1}
        {Age=90;Handi=8}
        {Age=79;Handi=12}
        {Age=99;Handi=18}
        {Age=75;Handi=8}
        {Age=76;Handi=9}
    ]


let SelectMember (mem:ClubMember) = 
    match mem with 
    | x when (mem.Age >= 55) && (mem.Handi > 7) -> "Senior"
    | _ -> "Open"


let PutAttributesInList (mem:ClubMember) = 
    match mem with 
    | _ -> [mem.Age; mem.Handi]

let Randomtests expected actual =  Assert.Equal("expected == actual?", OpenOrSenior expected, actual)
type _testcases = {_expected : int list list ; _actual : string list}
let mutable testCasesList = []

let GeneraterandomTests = 
    for i in 1..10 do 
        let mutable expected:int list list = []
        let mutable actual: string list = []
        for _i in 1..5 do 
            let mutable rndNumb = rand.Next(0,9)
            actual <- SelectMember values.[rndNumb] :: actual
            expected <- PutAttributesInList values.[rndNumb] :: expected
        testCasesList <- {_expected = expected; _actual = actual} :: testCasesList

[<Tests>]
let __suite = 
    testList "Random Tests!" [testCase "Should return test results.." <| (fun _ -> 
            for i in testCasesList do 
                Randomtests i._expected i._actual)
                ]
```